# Cloudflare and Firebase

Tags: firebase, caching, cloudflare

Is it possible to use Cloudflare to reduce the stress on my firebase landing page? If so, how would I go about setting that up? This is a relatively new concept to me.

Answer (score 10):

This is possible but not recommended. Firebase Hosting is already served via a global CDN and is built to take on enormous scale. By using CloudFlare acceleration (using it just for DNS is perfectly fine) in front of Firebase Hosting you are likely to slow down your site by adding an extra proxy layer between the client and the content.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use CloudFlare to reduce stress on Firebase landing page.
Add the following settings in CLoudFlare DNS records

***Settings:***

```
|------------|---------------|-----------------|------------|
|    Type    |      Name     |      Content    |     TTL    |
|------------|---------------|-----------------|------------|
|     A      | <domain-name> |   FirebaseIP1   |     Auto   |
|------------|---------------|-----------------|------------|
|     A      | <domain-name> |   FirebaseIP2   |     Auto   |
|------------|---------------|-----------------|------------|
|   CNAME    |      www      |  <domain-name>  |     Auto   |
|------------|---------------|-----------------|------------|
```

Comment: Yes, but how do you tell Firebase to accept the connection from there?  Custom CDN requires DNS record, so if you want the domain to be the same, then it won't work unless you just do simple domain verification with a file.